# correctly building and executing an .apk file

Tags: python, kivy

I build an app that scrapes the offers from my local supermarket. For the scraping I used beautifulsoup and for the ui and the usage on my android phone kivy. On Linux Ubuntu and Windows worked everything without errors the same goes with building the apk file. But when I try to run it on bluestacks, android studio or my phone it doesn't work. I got no errors nothing. In the emulators the app did not start and on my phone the app just closes after a short loading screen.

The log line:

> ## Compile platform
>
> ## Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,requests,bs4 --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a"
>
> --ndk-api=21'
>
> ## Cwd /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
>
> /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py:84:
> DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of
> importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
> import imp [INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs:
> armeabi-v7a [INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 27
> ^[[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27) [INFO]:    Requested API
> target 27 is available, continuing. [INFO]:    Found NDK dir in
> $ANDROIDNDK: /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
> [INFO]:    Found NDK version 19c [INFO]:    Getting NDK API version
> (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument [INFO]:    ccache is
> missing, the build will not be optimized in the future. [INFO]:
> Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9'] [INFO]:    Picking the
> latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9 [INFO]:    Of the existing
> distributions, the following meet the given requirements: [INFO]:
> myapp: min API 21, includes recipes (hostpython3, libffi, openssl,
> sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, sqlite3, python3, sdl2, setuptools,
> six, pyjnius, android, kivy, requests, bs4, certifi), built for archs
> (armeabi-v7a) [INFO]:    myapp has compatible recipes, using this one
>
> ## Build the application #7
>
> ## Copy application source from /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list
>
> ## Create directory /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/app
>
> ## Copy /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/main.py
>
> ## Copy /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/Webinteraction.py
>
> ## Copy /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/my.kv
>
> ## Package the application
>
> ## project.properties updated
>
> ## Gradle project detected, copy files /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/src/main/java
>
> ## Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name 'My Application' --version 0.1 --package org.test.myapp --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/app
>
> --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always
> --storage-dir="/home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a"
> --ndk-api=21'
>
> ## Cwd /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
>
> /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py:84:
> DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of
> importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
> import imp [INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs:
> armeabi-v7a [INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 27
> [INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27) [INFO]:    Requested API
> target 27 is available, continuing. [INFO]:    Found NDK dir in
> $ANDROIDNDK: /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
> [INFO]:    Found NDK version 19c [INFO]:    Getting NDK API version
> (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument [INFO]:    ccache is
> missing, the build will not be optimized in the future. [INFO]:
> Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9'] [INFO]:    Picking the
> latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9 [INFO]:    Of the existing
> distributions, the following meet the given requirements: [INFO]:
> myapp: min API 21, includes recipes (hostpython3, libffi, openssl,
> sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, sqlite3, python3, sdl2, setuptools,
> six, pyjnius, android, kivy, requests, bs4, certifi), built for archs
> (armeabi-v7a) [INFO]:    myapp has compatible recipes, using this one
> [INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given
> requirements: [INFO]:     myapp: min API 21, includes recipes
> (hostpython3, libffi, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf,
> sqlite3, python3, sdl2, setuptools, six, pyjnius, android, kivy,
> requests, bs4, certifi), built for archs (armeabi-v7a) [INFO]:
> myapp has compatible recipes, using this one [INFO]:    -> directory
> context
> /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2
> [INFO]:    <- directory context
> /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
> [INFO]:    -> directory context
> /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a
> Listing '/tmp/p4a-extra-env-5_vpn7lx'... Listing
> '/home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/app'...
> Compiling
> '/home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/app/Webinteraction.py'...
> Listing
> '/home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs'...
> Compiling
> '/home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/app/main.py'...
> Compiling
> '/home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/app/sitecustomize.py'...
> Listing
> '/home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle'...
> [INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 30.0.1
> [DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew assembleDebug [DEBUG]:       [DEBUG]:
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 7.0. [DEBUG]:    Use '--warning-mode all' to
> show the individual deprecation warnings. [DEBUG]:    See
> https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> [DEBUG]:       [DEBUG]:       BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 11s [DEBUG]:    27
> actionable tasks: 4 executed, 23 up-to-date
>
> [INFO]:    <- directory context
> /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
> [INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given
> requirements: [INFO]:     myapp: min API 21, includes recipes
> (hostpython3, libffi, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf,
> sqlite3, python3, sdl2, setuptools, six, pyjnius, android, kivy,
> requests, bs4, certifi), built for archs (armeabi-v7a) [INFO]:
> myapp has compatible recipes, using this one [INFO]:    # Copying
> android package to current directory [INFO]:    # Android package
> filename not found in build output. Guessing... [INFO]:    # Found
> android package file:
> /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/build/outputs/apk/debug/myapp__armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
> [INFO]:    # Add version number to android package [INFO]:    #
> Android package renamed to myapp__armeabi-v7a-debug-0.1-.apk [DEBUG]:
> -> running cp /home/user/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/build/outputs/apk/debug/myapp__armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
> myapp__armeabi-v7a-debug-0.1-.apk WARNING: Received a --sdk argument,
> but this argument is deprecated and does nothing. No
> setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
> Applying Java source code patches... Applying patch:
> src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch Warning: failed to apply patch
> (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied:
> src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
>
> ## Android packaging done!
>
> ## APK myapp-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk available in the bin directory user@user-VirtualBox:~/Dokumente/ordner/shopping_list$

Comment: We need to see logs for determine problem. Share your log. Also be sure your requirements is same with your libraries on Linux code.